# faces disappearing during render

Tags: modeling, animation, faces

[image]

I'm making a logo and for some reason when I render the animation the front of all the objects in the scene are missing even though during the preview it shows its all there

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file. We have no information about your project/seetings

Comment: how do i provide the blend file

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=3WwNdVm1" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3WwNdVm1/)